# Is there a way to create a union between collections in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm fairly new to LINQ and MongoDB. I have a problem where I have multiple databases in MongoDB with multiple collections, all containing documents that have the same structure. They are transactions created by clients. Each client has their own database and the transactions are stored based on the month that they were done in. The transaction records can get huge and the collections can get very large. The problem comes in when trying to draw a coherent list of these transactions across multiple databases and multiple collections while at the same time being able to use skip and limits on the amount of data drawn at a time. And then to make it more interesting, sort it by date as well...
The structure of the transaction looks something like this

```
{
  "_id" : 57,
  "date" : "Fri Apr 26 2019 18:51:22 GMT+0200 (UTC)", 
  "userId" : 12,
  "companyId" : 78,
  "MetaData" : "Large Meta Data",
}
```

When searching for transactions, the user can select a date constraint and the system would then display 20, 50, 100 or 200 records at a time with the ability to move to the next set or skip to a specific page number. In other words, something like this

```
First Back 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ... Next Last
```

I've created an algorithm that can calculate which records to skip to based on the limit of each page by checking the size of each collection that it will be pulling data from. However, this only works when pulling data for one client. I now have to do the same and combine the data from multiple clients for a specific time frame.

My hope is that I would be able to create something similar to a UNION from SQL where I can combine multiple collections and treat them as one while running an additional filter on them.
I've tried using LINQ

```
MongoClient cnDb = GetMongoClient();
IMongoDatabase db1 = cnDb.GetDatabase("Client1");
IMongoDatabase db2 = cnDb.GetDatabase("Client2");
var col1 = db1.GetCollection<ClientTrans>("Transactions-201904");
var col2 = db2.GetCollection<ClientTrans>("Transactions-201904");

var query = (from trans1 in col1.AsQueryable<ClientTrans>() select trans1).Union(from trans2 in col2.AsQueryable<ClientTrans>() select trans2);
foreach(ClientTrans trans in query) 
{

}
```

And that generates a very helpful error of

> The method Union is not supported in the expression tree:
>   aggregate([]).Select(trans1 =>
>   trans1).Union(aggregate([]).Select(trans2 => trans2))

Any help or insight would be appreciated...